# PHP 8 - Annotated method with Route Attribute not triggered for GET request

Tags: php, php-8

I am trying to load (include file) the GetRiskSummaryCommandHandler.php (GetRiskSummary\CommandHandler) at runtime dynamically, while resolving Route `api/risks` to HandleCommand (of class CommandHandler) method.

How can I do this?  If not can I modify any taken approach including modifying autoloader?

**My api class snippet looks like this:**

API.php

```
<?php
    abstract class API
    {
        public function processRequest() 
        {
            $id1 = $this->requestObj->id1;
            //$id2 = $this->requestObj->id2;
            $endpoint1 = $this->requestObj->endpoint1;
            $endpoint2 = $this->requestObj->endpoint2;
       
            $isDestination = in_array($id1, ['first', 'prev', 'next', 'last']);
            $numSetEndpoints = (int)isset($endpoint1) + (int)isset($endpoint2);
        
            switch($numSetEndpoints)
            {
                case 0:
                    if ($isDestination)
                        return json_decode($this->_response("No Endpoint: ", $endpoint1));
                    return json_decode($this->_response("ProjectAIM API"));
                case 1:
                    $className = $endpoint1.'Controller';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $className = $endpoint2.'Controller';
                    break;
            }

            $class = "GetRiskSummaryCommandHandler";
            $method = "HandleCommand";
            if (class_exists($class))
            {
                if (method_exists($class, $method))
                {
                    $response = (new $class($this->requestObj))->{$method}($this->requestObj);
                
                    if ($response['Succeeded'] == false)
                    {
                        return $response['Result'];
                    }
                    else if ($response['Succeeded'] == true)
                    {    
                        header("Content-Type: application/json");
                        return $this->_response($response);
                    }
                    else if ($response['Result'])
                    {
                        header("Content-Type: text/html");
                        return $this->_response($response);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
```

**Command Handler Snippet, uses a Route Attiribute

GetRiskSummaryCommandHandler.php

```
<?php
    namespace GetRiskSummary;

    use Infrastructure\CommandHandler;

    class GetRiskSummaryCommandHandler extends CommandHandler
    {
        #[Route("/api/risks", methods: ["GET"])]
        public function HandleCommand()
        {
            $qb = $this->getEntityManager()
                       ->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->select('*')
                ->from('Risks', 'Risks')
                ->orderBy('RiskID', 'DESC');    
            $query = $qb->getQuery();
            return $query->getResult();
        }
    }
```

Autoloader.php

```
<?php
    namespace Autoloader;

    class Autoloader
    {
        private static function rglob($pattern, $flags = 0) {
            $files = glob($pattern, $flags); 
            foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir) {
                $files = array_merge($files, self::rglob($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
            }
            return $files;
        }

        public static function ClassLoader($path)
        {
            $pathParts = explode("\\", $path);
            $path = $pathParts[array_key_last($pathParts)];
            $matches = self::rglob("*/$path*");
            foreach ($matches as $name) 
            {
                $filePath = realpath($name);
                if (file_exists($filePath))
                    include $filePath;       
            }
        }
    }

    spl_autoload_register("AutoLoader\AutoLoader::ClassLoader");
```

Comment: I do get the method triggered when I manually call it, but how do I do this via the Route attribute.

Comment: Looks like I might need to use Synfony to handle these annoatations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest missing feature of PHP Attributes would be that as far as I'm aware PHP Attributes are static and aren't evaluated at runtime. They are just glorified comments.

If it was true, we could do some truly amazing things like non-intrusively attaching pre/post-processing functions, just like what you wrote.

They work just like in symfony or doctrine. You can't use variables in them and you must write your own code to search your php class tree for attributes in the code and use php reflection to obtain the information and run the attributes.

To be honest it's pretty disappointing, although maybe it's just the first step that will be fixed in later versions of PHP.

But for now, I think what you're asking for is impossible. Because they are not running dynamically like you appear to be asking.

Comment: https://github.com/anime-tavern/php-attribute-router  seems to have resolved my issue, which I discovered from a tutorial video I came across https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6uv0z9Uy2g